# For similar value in column add new column frequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
Id  age number 
1    35   7
5    76   9
1    15   0
2    10   4
5    43   8
```

What i need to get is :

```
Id  age  number freq
1   35    7     2
5   76    9     2
1   15    0     1
2   10    4     1
5   43    8     1
```

Add a new colum freq , for each value in a column , we  takes all rows with same value in ID and count rows where the value of cat is less.

Answer (score 2):

If need counter in descending order use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby('Id').cumcount(ascending=False).add(1)
```

But if need counts values by `Id` use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html), output is different:

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby('Id')['Id'].transform('size')
```

Alternative with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['freq'] = df['Id'].map(df['Id'].value_counts())
```